# How to launch any launch.py file in ros2 humble?

Tags: slam, navigation, gazebo, ros2, roslaunch

My question is a little bit different. I am following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSuqO0p2mIk) and this [GitHub](https://github.com/noshluk2/ros2_learners) repository.

Problem:
How can I launch `turltebot3_dqn_stage4.launch.py` file instead of `turtlebot3_world.launch.py`.

I tried to make changes while following this video but nothing is happening, either `rviz` gives the world map instead of `stage4` map or it don't show the robot in the gazebo world.

Whenever I try to change the map, I usually edit `navigation.launch.py` file but after doing `colcon build` nothing happened, no changes are made. It simply launches the previous `world` map. This is what I want to get learn that how to change the world, what changes should I make in the code?

Comment: Thanks for updating question, it *might* be possible to re-open it. Regardless, I was reading the docs earlier, and on [this page](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/), under 6.1.2 point 2 it shows `roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch` so maybe try `roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_dqn_stage4.launch.py`. Please note that I am *totally* guessing. However, if it helps, I will turn this comment into an answer (once the question is re-opened). Leave a comment if this helps at all. Thanks.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, you do know that `turltebot3_dqn_stage4.launch.py` has a typo and should be `turtlebot3_dqn_stage4.launch.py` - that is to say that the `t` and `l`, in `turtle`, have been transposed..?

Comment: Thanks for your concern, for your kind information I've tried it many a time but it couldn't help. In the result either robot get vanish from the map or `Rviz` open the previous map `(world.launch)`